Azure App Insights - is there a way to configure it to ignore specific URLs across entire tenant
For context: Say for example I work in Healthcare IT and we have applications that pass PHI/PII that we do not want anything recorded (it just creates headaches).
Is there a way to tell App Insights in my tenant to ignore a group of URLs?
For example: I'd provide a list of urls like http://someservice.contsohealth.com/webhook and others and App Insights would just not see those anymore.

Please share the list of url's in the text format, unable to access the given URL?

You can use telemetry processors to filter the logs.

Refer this MsDoc to create a custom telemetry and configure it in ApplicationInsights.config file.

The url is fake and only meant to provide an example for consideration.

You can use Telemetry Processors to filter the traces before sending it to Application Insights.
As mentioned in the MSDoc, use ITelemetryProcessor and filter the data.

Create your own class with the logic to ignore the specific URL's (as per your requirement) by implementing ITelemetryProcessor.

public class FilterURL: ITelemetryProcessor 
{
    -------
}


If your App is .NET Framework, then register the created new class in ApplicationInsights.config

<TelemetryProcessors> 
    <Add Type="WebAppName.FilterURL, WebAppName">
    </Add> 
</TelemetryProcessors>


For .NET Core, register it in the Program.cs file.

builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<SuccessfulDependencyFilter>();


we do not want anything recorded (it just creates headaches).


You can also use Sampling to reduce the amount of telemetry sent to the Insights.


Been busy.  I'll be doing a POC with this and report back.  Thank you.
